# How do I stilize an input type range using html video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R9nyW/226/.

This is the html code:

```
<video id="video" width="500"  autoplay="true">
     <source src="http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>
<div id="Layer"></div>
<input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0">
```

The javascript code:

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
       $("#video").on("timeupdate", function () {
            var myVideo = $(this)[0];
            var value = (100 / myVideo.duration) * myVideo.currentTime;
            $("#seek-bar").val(value);
 /* x = "-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop("+value+", '#fff'),
        color-stop("+value+", '#000')
    );";
         $("#seek-bar").css("background-color", x);*/
        });
    });
```

What i want to achieve is that the left side of the input range to have a background-color X and the right side a background-color Y, while the video is playing. How can I do that, thx

Comment: Try use RGB that changes the  number values

Comment: it is the same with rgb

Comment: I said,  while the video is playing. NO static

Comment: So, while the video is playing. I want that the left side (the time passed from the video) to have a background-color: blue, and the right side (the time remaining from the video) to have a background-color: yellow. Srry if I offend you :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want that the left side (the time passed from the video) to have a
>   background-color: blue, and the right side (the time remaining from
>   the video) to have a background-color: yellow.

You should use the psuedo-selector `::-moz-range-progress` which represents the portion of the "track" passed.

```
input[type=range]::-moz-range-progress {
  background: blue;
  height: 1em;
}
```

This is non-standard though and has limited browser compatability. Customize as you wish.

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/uh7axfm5/3/)

[JsFiddle with HTML5 progressbar](https://jsfiddle.net/uh7axfm5/11/)

---

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-range-progress)

Comment: It works only on firefox. Can you do that also on chrome ? it would be great :)

Comment: As I mentioned, this has very limited browser compatability. It's still what you're after.. For better compatability, look into HTML5's progressbar.. See updated [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uh7axfm5/11/). Unfortunately, also fairly limited. Psuedo-elements works very inconsitently across browsers..

Comment: can I ask why 2600? if I put a longer video, it doesn't syncronize with the progress bar

Answer (score -1):

Basically, first remove all appareance from all browser and after apply apparence with browser constructor selector:
- to the slider-thumb and
- to the range-thumb

It's seems that is what you want:
- [Styling Cross-Browser Compatible Range Inputs with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/).

But this will not cover all browser.

For a range fully designed in way you want on all browser you will do a binding from HTMLElement(s) that represent a fake range that change in real time the range value.

It's also possible to apply a two-way binding to allow whatever change the real value of range to report change on your fake range.

Comment: Srry I don;t see an example in your URL, when the left side has a background-color X and the right side has a background-color  Y.